# Blazor Webassembly, DatabaseCRUD: Internal Server Error 500 with published version

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

**Problem Details**
I have a Blazor project with a simple Database-CRUD (create, read, update, delete) example. It works properly when I run it within Visual Studio but if I publish it the program runs into an error.

**Project Details**
IDE is Visual Studio 2019. Project is Blazor Webassembly. I tried .NET CORE 3.1 and .NET 5.0. Database is SQL Server 2019. IIS for publishing.

**Code Details**
Database access is working with mapping (Scaffold-DbContext). I use the nuggets “Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools” and “Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer”.

This is the read command:

```
using var httpResponse = await Http.GetAsync("/api/DataLrs/Index");
```

This is the read command-snippet I use for more error details:

```
using var httpResponse = await Http.GetAsync("/api/DataLrs/Index");
if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // set error message for display, log to console and return
    errorMessage = httpResponse.ReasonPhrase;
    Console.WriteLine($"There was an error! {errorMessage}");
    return;
}
// convert http response data to UsersResponse object
dataLrsList = await httpResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<DataLrs[]>();
```

**Error Details**
When I publish the project with IIS and try to execute the same commands I get the following error in the browser:
Internal Server Error
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: net_http_message_not_success_statuscode, 500

**Solution Attempts Details**
As already mentioned, when I run it in Visual Studio it works without any problems. I already googled and tried several stuff but nothing really works.
How can I get a better error description?
Is anybody familiar with this problem?
I realized many people have the same/similar problem, but I couldn’t find a clear solution
Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you're using EF Core, so have you migrated your databse stuff on the published webserver? Locally the databse is initialized and updated via the Package Manager Console, but changes have to be migrated to the live SQL server.

We could also need more information, like: Are you using the localDB stuff; what's your connection string; how does your method "/api/DataLrs/Index" look like?; etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, I am using EF Core. Sorry! Forgot to mention that important detail.

**Database Details**
To make it not too complicated I am using a database on my pc and I am also publishing (IIS) on my pc. If all works, I would proceed with a server.
I retrieved my connection string via Visual Studio’s SQLServerObjectExplorer. I use for both modes (debug, publish) the same connection string which is stored in appsettings.json.
This is the connection string:
Data Source=CND823509T\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DataComposerWebDBTest;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

**Method Details**
Here are some of my method details, I will just copy the important lines (hope that is enough). I got the structure from a general example I googled. As already mentioned, locally it works.

RazorePage.razor

```
dataLrsList = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<DataLrs[]>("/api/DataLrs/Index")
```

DataLrsAccessLayer.cs

```
public IEnumerable<DataLrs> GetData()
{
    try
    {
        return _context.DataLrs.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

DataLrsController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/DataLrs/Index")]
public IEnumerable<DataLrs> Index()
{
    return _dataLrs.GetData();
}
```

**Questions Details**
Do you need more details?
What do you mean with localDB stuff?

Thanks!